# How to exit prompt when starting a weblogic administration server remotely?

Tags: weblogic

I am trying to start Weblogic Admin server using start-up script (./startWeblogic.sh) from a remote host using a different user. The server starts fine but prompt is stuck, it does not return

Background: We have multiple admin servers in different environment and the requirement is all has to be started/stopped from a central automation server which has a password less sudo connectivity to all Weblogic hosts.

I am using command :

{ssh -l user remote-address     '/spare/app/oracle/product/Middleware/user_projects/domains/example_domain/bin/./startWebLog`enter code here`ic.sh & > /dev/null < /dev/null'}

As admin server is spawning a child shell, the parent shell is not closing and it keeps holding the prompt.

Please Advise.

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach is to use the nohup command.  Try this:

ssh -l user remote-address '/usr/bin/nohup /spare/app/oracle/product/Middleware/user_projects/domains/example_domain/bin/./startWebLogic.sh & > /dev/null < /dev/null'